# sort() into dropdown menu with list from url

Tags: javascript

I have a [URL which links](https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all) to an alphabetized list in object form. I also have a drop down menu containing only the letters 'A-D.' I need be able to use the dropdown menu to select alphabetically through letters A to D. My HTML for the dropdown menu:

```
 <select id="breed-dropdown" name="select-breed">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
      <option value="d">d</option>
    </select>
```

I suspect I need to use sort() but I am a new student to Javascript and so cannot quite put it together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am only trying to achieve exactly what i wrote above. This is for a simple student lab.

Comment: I need to take the objects which begin with the letters "A-D" which are listed in the URL I posted, " and have them sortable by using a dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an object like this:

```
{
  "affenpinscher": [],
  "african": [],
  "australian": ["shepherd"],
  // ...
}
```

The `group()` function below will produce an object like this:

```
{
  a: [
    { "affenpinscher": [] },
    { "african": [] },
    { "australian": ["shepherd"] },
    // ...
  b: [
    // ...
}
```

Where 'a', 'b' etc are keys passed as the second parameter (defaulting to the entire alphabet).  It does this using `reduce` on the keys of the passed object.

```js
function group(data, keys) {
  keys = keys || 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  let breeds = Object.keys(data);
  return breeds.reduce((acc, breed) => {
    const key = breed.substring(0,1)
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];
      acc[key].push({ [breed]: data[breed] })
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

let data = getData().message;
let grouped = group(data, 'abcd'.split(''))
console.log(grouped)

function getData() {
  return {
    "message": {
      "affenpinscher": [],
      "african": [],
      "airedale": [],
      "akita": [],
      "appenzeller": [],
      "australian": ["shepherd"],
      "basenji": [],
      "beagle": [],
      "bluetick": [],
      "borzoi": [],
      "bouvier": [],
      "boxer": [],
      "brabancon": [],
      "briard": [],
      "buhund": ["norwegian"],
      "bulldog": ["boston", "english", "french"],
      "bullterrier": ["staffordshire"],
      "cattledog": ["australian"],
      "chihuahua": [],
      "chow": [],
      "clumber": [],
      "cockapoo": [],
      "collie": ["border"],
      "coonhound": [],
      "corgi": ["cardigan"],
      "cotondetulear": [],
      "dachshund": [],
      "dalmatian": [],
      "dane": ["great"],
      "deerhound": ["scottish"],
      "dhole": [],
      "dingo": [],
      "doberman": [],
      "elkhound": ["norwegian"],
      "entlebucher": [],
      "eskimo": [],
      "finnish": ["lapphund"],
      "frise": ["bichon"],
      "germanshepherd": [],
      "greyhound": ["italian"],
      "groenendael": [],
      "havanese": [],
      "hound": ["afghan", "basset", "blood", "english", "ibizan", "plott", "walker"],
      "husky": [],
      "keeshond": [],
      "kelpie": [],
      "komondor": [],
      "kuvasz": [],
      "labradoodle": [],
      "labrador": [],
      "leonberg": [],
      "lhasa": [],
      "malamute": [],
      "malinois": [],
      "maltese": [],
      "mastiff": ["bull", "english", "tibetan"],
      "mexicanhairless": [],
      "mix": [],
      "mountain": ["bernese", "swiss"],
      "newfoundland": [],
      "otterhound": [],
      "ovcharka": ["caucasian"],
      "papillon": [],
      "pekinese": [],
      "pembroke": [],
      "pinscher": ["miniature"],
      "pitbull": [],
      "pointer": ["german", "germanlonghair"],
      "pomeranian": [],
      "poodle": ["miniature", "standard", "toy"],
      "pug": [],
      "puggle": [],
      "pyrenees": [],
      "redbone": [],
      "retriever": ["chesapeake", "curly", "flatcoated", "golden"],
      "ridgeback": ["rhodesian"],
      "rottweiler": [],
      "saluki": [],
      "samoyed": [],
      "schipperke": [],
      "schnauzer": ["giant", "miniature"],
      "setter": ["english", "gordon", "irish"],
      "sheepdog": ["english", "shetland"],
      "shiba": [],
      "shihtzu": [],
      "spaniel": ["blenheim", "brittany", "cocker", "irish", "japanese", "sussex", "welsh"],
      "springer": ["english"],
      "stbernard": [],
      "terrier": ["american", "australian", "bedlington", "border", "cairn", "dandie", "fox", "irish", "kerryblue", "lakeland", "norfolk", "norwich", "patterdale", "russell", "scottish", "sealyham", "silky", "tibetan", "toy", "welsh", "westhighland", "wheaten", "yorkshire"],
      "tervuren": [],
      "vizsla": [],
      "waterdog": ["spanish"],
      "weimaraner": [],
      "whippet": [],
      "wolfhound": ["irish"]
    },
    "status": "success"
  }
}
```

Some notes on the function:

```
  keys = keys || 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

This says, if the keys we wish to restrict ourselves to are not passed, use the entire alphabet.

[The `||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) results in either the left or the right operand, whichever is not false or null or zero (false-like). [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) splits a string into an array around some delimiter. If an empty string (`''`) is passed as a delimiter, it splits at every character in the string.

```
  let breeds = Object.keys(data);
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of an object's keys. Each key is a breed in the OP.

```
  return breeds.reduce((acc, breed) => {
```

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) visits every element in an array, invoking a function with an "accumulator" and each array element (`(acc, breed) => {`). reduce() returns the value of the accumulator after each element in the array has been visited.

The accumulator is initialized with the the last reduce parameter. See the last line of reduce:

```
  }, {}). // this empty object will become the alphabetic index
```

For this problem, the code block aims to create an index object -- one whose keys are letters (single character strings), and whose values are arrays of objects pairing breeds with sub-breeds.

```
    const key = breed.substring(0,1)
```

[`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) does what its name implies, getting the first letter of the breed, located at the zero-th index.

```
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
```

Array [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) also does what its name implies, answering true if the receiving array includes the value parameter. In the OP, we only care about letters in the `keys` array, ignoring the rest.

```
      if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];
```

This line says, "if the accumulator doesn't have the key, add it and give it a value of an empty array which will hold the sub-breeds. On the line after, we can now be assured that the accumulator either already had the single-letter key or just got it.

```
      acc[key].push({ [breed]: data[breed] })
```

`acc[key]` is the array of sub-breeds. [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds to the end of arrays. In the OP case, we're adding a new object:  `{ [breed]: data[breed] }` which is a literal that says, the key is the breed (from the `breeds` array we're iterating), and the value is the sub-breeds from the api data.

```
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
}
```

For it to keep state, the block in reduce must return the accumulator.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. I am not sure of how to go about implementing it but I will try.

Comment: @Michael, I had some time on my hands, so I added an extensive exposition of the solution.

Comment: Wow, thank you Danh.

Comment: @Michael, ordinarily, when you use an answer on SO, you mark it with the check to indicate to future readers that you applied it successfully.

Comment: Danh, I have not applied it successfully and it might take me several days to even begin to figure out how to do so.

Comment: I do not see "a check" anywhere, but when I find it I will "check" it regardless. Thanks again.